# Unable to get the same checksum value for a copied file

Tags: 16.04, backup, md5sum, checksums

**UPDATE 1:**

Attempted rsync as suggested by Jos:

```
$ cd /media/oshirowanen/
$ rsync -avv HDD1/file.iso HDD2/file.iso 
sending incremental file list
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
20GB-unknown.iso is uptodate
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 81 bytes  received 119 bytes  400.00 bytes/sec
total size is 20,003,880,960  speedup is 100,019,404.80
```

Checksum attempted again, but still different.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have 2 usb connected external drives.  E1 (external drive 1) has a file.  I have made a copy of this file from E1 to E2 (external drive 2).

I then did a `md5sum file.iso` on E1 and `md5sum file.iso` on E2.

For some reason, the checksum value of E2 did not match the checksum value of E1.

As I am trying to backup file.iso, I'm guessing I should be concerned that the file did not copy across properly.  If that is the reason for the different checksum values, how do I copy the file perfectly intact?

I have tried a basic copy and paste twice, and both times the values did not match.

Comment: Yes, a mismatched hash would be concerning for a backup file. Is this on a plain install of Ubuntu Desktop? What formats are the filesystems on the external drives?

Comment: @mjb2kmn, The source disk is Ext4 (2TB), and the destination disk is LUKS/Ext4 (3TB).  file.iso is 20GB.  Also, yes, this is done using a plain old install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 64bit.

Comment: Could you try this with `rsync`? In principle, this should go rather fast because `rsync` copies only [those blocks that are different.](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/)

Comment: @Jos, I've added rsync details in OP.

Comment: Have you ever run a memory check on your hardware?  Does fsck report any filesystem problems?  Does smartctl -a report any disk problems?